# Infinite Scroll Breaking jQuery Event

Tags: jquery, ajax, infinite-scroll

I have a function in jQuery that when you hover over a div it, it disappears and shows another div in its place. The function works well until I load items using Ajax for infinite scrolling. I know it has to do with binding the new elements (from what I've read, using on()), but as I am new to jQuery, I have no idea how to implement this change.I've been trying for the past few hours, but have made no headway.

(Specific problem: new_social hover is broken on ajax load for new loaded items)

Any help would be much appreciated, especially in code form! Thanks so much!

Here are the functions:

```
$("a.share").hover(function(){
  $(this).closest($('div.new_story')).children("div.new_social_buttons").show();
  $(this).closest(".new_social").hide();
 },
 function(){
  });


$("div.new_social_buttons").hover(function(){

},
function(){
  $(this).hide();
   $(this).closest($('div.new_story')).children("div.new_social").show();
});
```

Here is the ajax load function:

```
jQuery.ias({
container : '#middle',
item: '.new_story',
pagination: '#pagination',
next: 'a.next',
loader: '<img src="loader.gif"/>',
history: false

 });
```

Here is where I got the infinite scroll, I think it has the jQuery behind the function call:
https://github.com/webcreate/Infinite-Ajax-Scroll

Thanks again!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It just sounds like the event needs to be delegated to a static parent element that exists during page load.

**The delegated a.share handler**

```
$(document).on({
    mouseenter: function(){
        $(this).closest($('div.new_story')).children("div.new_social_buttons").show();
        $(this).closest(".new_social").hide();
    },
    mouseleave: function(){
        //looks like nothing going on here; just providing for future ref.
    }
}, 'a.share');
```

**The delegated div.new_social_buttons handler**

```
$(document).on({
    mouseenter: function(){
        //looks like nothing going on here; just providing for future ref.
    },
    mouseleave: function(){
        $(this).hide();
        $(this).closest($('div.new_story')).children("div.new_social").show();
    }
}, 'div.new_social_buttons');
```

When using `.on()` you cannot use the normal `.hover()` wrapper method. Instead, you must supply a `mouseenter and`mouseleave` object with the functionality declared within.

Also, important to note, is that you should replace `document` with any static parent element to save performance. Because jQuery's delegated selectors leverage javascript's [querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll) method, the performance gain will be negligible, but could become burdensome on a deeply nested site. This is why I suggest binding to something lower within the tree that is static.

Comment: By any chance do you know what code would go within the first part of the mouseenter to load the facebook and twitter buttons within the div?